# CSRF protection techniques

Tags: csrf, csrf-protection

Can someone point me to information on how to protect applications from CSRF?

Any code related to this.

I am using extjs for the UI, Java on the backend and tomcat server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSRF issue in Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344868/csrf-issue-in-tomcat)

Answer (score 1):

Use of the session id in the way the dan_waterworth suggests, while easy, is very poor protection. The attacker only needs to capture the session id cookie and then can circumvent the protection for the life of the session.

The session id is a cookie so it's submitted with any request. So all an attacker needs to do to capture the sessionid is to cause your application submit a request to a server under the attacker's control. This could be done by a cross-site scripting attack but can also be done by framing the app and submitting the iFrame's forms (there are other ways to do this).

The interaction that needs to be protected from CSRF should include information that the attacker cannot possibly know in advance (a CSRF Token) that is unique per session, per page and per form then ideally used only once. The CSRF token should be submitted in the form, and not in a cookie (for the reason mentioned above). See the 'implementation example' in the [OWASP CSRF protection cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for details and a sample implementation. Some web application engines (e.g. Tomcat 8) and frameworks (e.g Spring, JSF) have protections that you can apply by turning on a configuration.

Answer (score 0):

yes, I have a simple solution that has worked well for me. For each post request, send the sessionid in the data via javascript (obtained from the cookie) and on the server side it just needs to check that the sessionid cookie and the sessionid in the data are the same for every post request.

Comment: I am using Tomacat server in my poject.

Comment: I've never used java to make a website before, (python rules), can you add code that gets called for each request?