# CSRF protection in Tomcat

Tags: javascript, tomcat6, csrf, csrf-protection

How can I prevent CSRF vulnerabilities in Tomcat?

I am using the Tomcat server for my application, and I need to protect my application from CSRF attacks. Is there any technique to do this?

Comment: You don't need to post questions twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSRF protection techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343323/csrf-protection-techniques)

Comment: Your question is kind of vague. Is it your application you're worried about or the Tomcat itself? In both cases, could you provide some information about Tomcat version, language, frameworks used, etc?

Comment: I think it is both cases,

Currently I am using tomcat 5.5.13, in my project<

Comment: I need in both cases,

Currently I am using tomcat 5.5.13.

For IU front Extjs and javascript, backend Java and controlling jsp are used.   

If not posible please give me solution for the Tomcat side.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 6.0.30 have build in CSRF protection (you need to activate it).

http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/05/09/cross-site-request-forgery

Comment: I spend more than one day with it, and get it working, but I don't link this implementation.

Comment: The link does not exist anymore, but Google has a cache: https://s.apache.org/peqS

Answer (score 0):

First the Tomcat; Prove me wrong, but I think CSRF vulnerabilities do currently not exist for the container itself.

If you worry about any other Tomcat vulnerabilities, I would suggest to subscribe to some of the mailing lists at [SecurityFocus](http://www.securityfocus.com/), in particular the BugTraq, and frequently check the [Tomcat 5 Security page](http://tomcat.apache.org/security-5.html). 
And the most important part: Keep your Tomcat patched and up to date.

Regarding the application, it's kind of hard to tell you how to secure your application, without knowing it or seeing code, but [here in the OWASP Wiki](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_CSRF_%28OWASP-SM-005%29), there are some genereal approaches to understand, avoid and test against CSRF vulnerabilities.

Another option would be to early-adopt [Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi), which features a ['CSRF Prevention Filter'](http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/3904871). There is also some guy, who wants to [backport this to Tomcat 5/6](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-dev/201005.mbox/%3C4BE452F2.6040305@apache.org%3E).